# .addClass Javascript code not executing properly - WordPress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a class (`.load`) to a div (`#widget2`) on page load using JS. I've tested the code in Developer Tools using a snippet and it works fine, but I just can't get it to work after inserting the code into the page header and loading the page. I thought there might be a conflict with a plugin but I don't think that's the case. Hoping someone can help me figure this problem out.

Here's the site. It's on WordPress: https://greenvillesolarsolutions.com/
What I'm trying to do is delay a background video from displaying (which is hidden with CSS) by adding a css class once the page has loaded. Below is my html, css and JS.

HTML:

```html
<div class="vc_video-bg vc_hidden-xs">

<iframe id="widget2" class="inner" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" 
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" title="YouTube video player"></iframe>

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#widget2 {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

#widget2.load {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

JS:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#widget2').addClass('load');
});
</script>
```

It's driving nuts that I can't get this to work. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you sure the id `#widget` is unique? If it isn't, the code will not work.

Comment: There's a significant error in the JavaScript console you should look at.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason it seems like `$` is not working as alias for `jQuery` on your website. This is evident by seeing this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

Try this:

```
jQuery('#widget2').addClass('load');
```

Comment: Thanks @redFur I tried the following but it still isn't working: <script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#widget2').addClass('load');
});
</script>

Comment: @user2466010 did you try  `<script type='text/javascript'> jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('#widget2').addClass('load'); }); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the vanilla solution, `document.querySelector('#widget2').classList.add('load')`? I tried that in the devtools console on the page and it worked.